# My recursive type errors with "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts" when applied to Window or Element

Tags: typescript

I have a type that I am using to "auto mock" interface types in Jest tests. After updating to the latest TypeScript and latest Jest versions I am getting the `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)` error.

I have also noticed that calculating the type takes a long time and I feel I have designed the type wrong.

The objective of the type is to take an interface as a generic property and return a type where the methods are `jest.Mock` functions and if the properties are not basic types, then recursively mock the nested type.

```js
interface Foo {
  foo(): void
  bar: {
    bar(): void
  }
  foobar: string
}

type MockedFoo = MockedInterface<Foo>

// Essentially
interface MockedFoo {
  foo: jest.Mock<void, []>
  bar: {
    bar: jest.Mock<void, []>
  }
  foobar: string
}
```

My type looks like:

```js
type JestMock<T, Y extends Array<any>> = (...args: Y) => T

export interface CalledWithMock<T, Y extends Array<any>> extends JestMock<T, Y> {
  calledWith: (...args: Y) => JestMock<T, Y>;
}

export type MockedInterface<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer B
    ? CalledWithMock<B, A> & T[K]
    : MockedInterface<T[K]> & T[K];
};
```

With this implementation, if I mock something like `Window` or `Element`, I have the error stated earlier (perhaps because it's potentially self-referencing?).

```js
function foo(_e: Element) {}

const d = document.createElement('div')
const dm = mockElement<HTMLDivElement>()

foo(d)
foo(dm) // Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

Here's a playground with my exact scenario:

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUhDOwCyB7AxgawDwBUA0UAmlBAB7AQB2AJvFAIIBOjAhiFi5SAHzdQC8UABQA6MS0YBzeAC4iASgF8cAKBVkwKRsCgBLShUYAzFmmgBhFgBsrEagHVdwABapMuAsTIUadJq3ZOHj5vKlpYBGR0bHwiPgBvFSgoNGtbBydnOVFxKVkFJQjENxjPbgBuFQBfNQ0tHVBIKBK7AEkDCGNTCFw%20QUTkgG0AaT1KKAwIEBQjKBwAXTkcEfmScjC6HJEJaTl9I06GRX4%20fcOAISTkqAB%20KEsbO0cXEqxzgno%20ADI5lavkuQtajtQwmMy4FbfX7DeaVKqVFTUCBoKwSaBGACulDQwF0KHGAFtogBRWwEqjAXBrHzhUkQckGbhCeSA6JtDpdcE4bhqFSY7G4-FQIwoFBCAD6EDkdIZwEU8RqKjQ%20MQUGoAjV6AxspEaEYEBYFBlFKEAHJqLoAG6m%20RKlU6agEjVEzDGgxYAASOCQABkACJWt3AJm2vmioTUW0isWO%20RAA)

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] without any code unnecessary for demonstrating the issue.  I'm slogging through this removing most of the stuff in your `jest` module and still reproducing the error. That's something you could probably do before asking the question so that people who want to answer can get right to work on helping (or maybe even you would figure it out yourself in the process)

Comment: My bad, I will update the example without it

Comment: My guess here is that distributing the `& T[K]` over both sides of the conditional type is causing bad things to happen with it tests `MockedInterface<Elementlike>` against `Element` and that you should write `T[K] & (T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer B ? CalledWithMock<B, A> : MockedInterface<T[K]>)` instead, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w11Jlw)... but without a nice clean [mre] it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Updated with a minimal reproducible example. Sorry I originally collapsed the jest module in the editor and forgot that it was actually a huge block of code.

Comment: So then does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WK8BGw) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer (although the explanation for why the original was worse for recursion limits would be a bit hand-wavy as I'm not an expert in the compiler itself).  If not, let me know what's missing and I'll see if I can address it.

Comment: This works exactly as expected, thanks!

Comment: All right, I'll write up an answer but it will probably not be until sometime tomorrow (it's getting to be sleepytime in my time zone)

Answer (score 2):

My initial suggestion is to replace

```
export type MockedInterface<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer B
    ? CalledWithMock<B, A> & T[K]
    : MockedInterface<T[K]> & T[K];
};
```

with

```
export type MockedInterface<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer B
    ? T[K] & CalledWithMock<B, A>
    : T[K] & MockedInterface<T[K]>;
};
```

That is, move the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `T[K]` to the first part of each expression in which it appears.  Generally speaking, unless `X` and `Y` have coinciding function-typed signatures or properties, `X & Y` is equivalent to `Y & X` (intersections of function types specifically become [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) and order of overload call signatures matters when it comes to resolving overloads).

You can check that this works as desired:

```
foo(dm); // okay
```

---

I don't know if I can find an authoritative answer as to *why* this version behaves better.  It is definitely true that order sometimes has an effect on performance (as in [microsoft/TypeScript#43437](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43437)) but I don't see anything specifically about intersections like this.

My *guess* is that the compiler evaluates an intersection type like `F<T> & G<T>` by first computing `F<T>`, then computing `G<T>`, and then intersecting them together.  If `G<T>` is easy to compute and `F<T>` is hard to compute, then `U extends G<T> & F<T>` might have better performance than `U extends F<T> & G<T>`.

In your case, the compiler needed to check if `MockedInterface<HTMLDivElement> extends Element`.  In order to do that, it has to iterate over each property of `HTMLDivElement` and evaluate either `CalledWithMock<B, A> & T[K]` or `MockedInterface<T[K]> & T[K]`.  Assuming it always evaluates the left term first, this ends up forcing the compiler to recurse all the way into every property and subproperty of `HTMLDivElement` before being able to decide if `MockedInterface<HTMLDivElement>` is assignable to `Element`.  If `HTMLDivElement` is itself recursively defined or has lots of dependencies (I think both are true) then the compiler could easily hit recursion limits.

On the other hand, with `T[K] & CalledWithMock<B, A>` or `T[K] & MockedInterface<T[K]>`, the compiler should easily see that each property `K` of `MockedInterface<HTMLDivElement>` is assignable to `HTMLDivElement[K]`, and thus that `MockedInterface<HTMLDivElement>` is itself assignable to `HTMLDivElement`, without having to go down any further.

This guess may or may not turn out to actually be true; if you care about a canonical answer to that, you might want to file an issue in TypeScript's GitHub repo asking about it (after searching for existing issues of course).

---

Anyway, since you are intersecting with `T[K]` regardless of which branch of [the conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) is taken, you can actually move it out of the conditional type entirely:

```
type MockedInterface<T> = T & {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] & (T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer B
    ? CalledWithMock<B, A>
    : MockedInterface<T[K]>);
}
```

And since you'd be intersecting each property from `T` with `T[K]`, you can probably move the intersection completely out of the mapped type without changing things (something like `{[K in keyof T]: T[K] & F<T, K>}` is more or less the same as `{[K in keyof T]: T[K]} & {[K in keyof T]: F<T, K>}`, which is more or less the same as `T & {[K in keyof T]: F<T, K>}`.  Like this:

```
type MockedInterface<T> = T & {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer B
    ? CalledWithMock<B, A>
    : MockedInterface<T[K]>;
}
```

Each of these changes should make it even easier for the compiler to evaluate `MockedInterface<T>`.  Certainly `MockedInterface<HTMLDivElement>` will be quickly seen as assignable to `HTMLDivElement` which is itself assignable to `Element`, and the compiler does not even need to try to recurse down into the mapped type to check that.

So my final suggestion is probably this version, where `MockedInterface<T> = T & ...`.  Obviously you need to test against your use cases; just like there are some situations (like overloads) in which `X & Y` might be different form `Y & X`, there are some situations in which this version with `T &`  might be different from the nested subproperty intersection version (For example, if `T` is itself a function type, then `{[K in keyof T]: T[K]}` will not be callable even though `T` is).  If these differences don't matter to you, great.  If they do, then you will need to tailor your implementation to meet your needs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=36&ssc=70&pln=35&pc=1#code/FDAuE8AcFMAICloGdQFkD2BjA1gHgCoA0sAmrNAB6jQB2AJkrAIIBOLAhuLuzeAHx9YAXlgAKAHST2LAOZIAXKQCUwwfhCVI6FqFgBLGtRYAzdpjgBhdgBtr0OgHU9oABYYcBYmUrV6jVhxcPPyCPrQMCMhoWHhEpIIA3sCwKbCYNnaOzi6KElKyCsqqkSjusV58ANzAAL4gwAD0AFTkFFo6sBAwsGX2AJKG0CZm0ASCIkmpsADaANL6NLDY0ODoxrD4ALqK+HObrb4ReeLScooGxkPMKkKCF1cAQsmpAPywVrb2Tq5luA-ETEEADINntnilFL06AMjKZzAQ9sDQbNNtUapVYE0GvVmpptLounAoTChnDRvhxrBJqk5gslis1httsj9mE-GJJCcCucaJcWNdivd+U8pm9dijYCCPplvm4Yn8AXxwbAdntJT0Yv1BsN4eLNlVapUsTiWoSNTgtbCRmNhBt1dSUrSDPTVustqqJSDRHqDuFGMdToUhQLbgs+bARa93hkvtlfv9mEqppDNdDtWSESi+Eo0ZjsWAoETUySdeTKfh7cqnYtlq6mR7WVQ-Rz8mcw1cmDc7rzHsq3tLYz95QnAcqUxa01bdYi0SA6NBMNZpHBjABXGiYUB6dCLAC2MQAonZd7RQARfeyj9AT4Y+KIlOPlpPSdaKSA1xutzvYMZ0OhRAA+tAihXjeoAqAksB1MAmA7igsB0LadBYKuYHiJgLDQOw1CgaeogAOR0HoABu+FKDBcG6HQu62vuOC4YYuAABL4KgAAyAAiJEMaAd7kQ0DRpJRCG7o+lovvCLHsVxxE8UqwC-v+dDkYpojUTmsACbA6DYJwQA)